# Debian 8 Jessie not displaying startup services and messages

Tags: debian, startup, debian-jessie

Recently I setup a new box with Debian 8 Jessie (I used Debian 6 and 7 on other boxes). I was disappointed to see the startup messages only on 2 or 3 text lines. No more list of startup services written "OK" or "Failed", or filesystem details with fsck etc.

Searched the web, I found to remove the "quiet" option from the /etc/default/grub file. I did that, recovered the messages I used to see on previous versions but also a lot of garbage, making the text scrolling so fast I couldn't read anything.

I liked to see the "light" messages before to have an overview of the box health when restarting. How could I have this back on Jessie ?
(Checked on the older boxes, the "quiet" option was present, so it seems the difference is not there).

I don't care about having a "beautiful" startup screen, these are only servers ...

Thanks for your help

Comment: I also liked being able to read the start-up messages and I too disabled the `quiet` GRUB option after installing Debian 8. Then I realised that the messages flew by too quickly to read. I just accepted this as a consequence of the move to Systemd. After all, one if its advantages is fast start-up.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me out the systemd move, I searched the web to understand the thing, and I'll go the same way than you : accept ...

Answer (score 5):

As it was already pointed out, Debian 8 Jessie comes with `systemd` init system by default, which behaves differently than older SysV init system. To get your startup messages back you need to make following changes:

1. Add `systemd.show_status=1` to the kernel options list. The easiest way to do so is to add to the `/etc/default/grub`:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet systemd.show_status=1"
   ```

   and run `update-grub2`.
2. In  principal, that should be enough to get your messages back on the console. But, there is another catch - `systemd` is also controlling TTY allocation now and invocation of `getty`, so `tty1` will be cleared before the `login` prompt is shown. To disable clearing `tty1` you need to create file, for ex. `noclear.conf`, in `/etc/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service.d/` directory with the content:

   ```
   [Service]
   TTYVTDisallocate=no
   ```

With those two steps you'll get your startup messages back.